# Django: Change field label in admin doesn't work

Tags: django, django-admin

Unfortunately, I'm still using django 1.4 and the verbose_name doesn't work for foreign keys.
It is there a way to change the label of a foreign key. For now, it is not working:

```
class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(TestProduct, verbose_name='test product', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

## ProductVariant

```
class ProductVariantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TestProduct.objects.order_by("product__article_code"))
    test_software = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TestSoftware.objects.order_by("name"))     
    class Meta:
        model = ProductVariant

class ProductVariantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields=["product", "test_software", "test_variables", "name", "description"]
    list_display = ("name", "product_name", "test_software_name", "test_variables", "description")
    search_fields = ["name"]
    form = ProductVariantForm
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try that: `product = models.ForeignKey(TestProduct, verbose_name=u'test product', on_delete=models.PROTECT)` If it works i will post my answer.

Comment: @Silwestpl it does'nt work :'(

Answer (score 1):

`verbose_name` should work with Django 1.4 according to the 1.4 [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names).

I think because you're overriding the field in the form it's not using the verbose name for the label. What you could do is set the label on the ModelChoiceField.

```
class ProductVariantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Test Product", queryset=TestProduct.objects.order_by("product__article_code"))
    test_software = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TestSoftware.objects.order_by("name"))     
    class Meta:
        model = ProductVariant
```

I'm not quite sure how to use the model's verbose name on the field though, so you might have to define it twice.